# Trouble with one to many relationship hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

hello i'm trying to learn one to many mapping but i really having trouble with hibernate. I was able to persist to database but when trying to apply one to many relationship it doesn't persist to DB and also doesn't display the relationship when viewing the response body in postman. I really need help been on this problem since yesterday morning. I have looked on tutorials on youtube and on internet but every tutorial seem basic and when applying same idea no success. I have an entity person and another entity organization. A person can belong up to one organization but different persons can belong to the same organization. So my approach was using a one to many relationship.

Below is my entity of Organization:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="organization")
public class Organization {

    @Id
    @Column(name="org_Id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String name, description;

    @OneToMany(/*fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL*/)
    @JoinTable(joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="org_Id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="person_Id"))
   // @JsonIgnore

    //@JoinColumn(name="org_Id")
    private Collection<Person> personCollection = new ArrayList<Person>();

    public Collection<Person> getPersonCollection() {
        return personCollection;
    }

    public void setPersonCollection(Collection<Person> personCollection) {
        this.personCollection = personCollection;
    }

    private Address address;

    public Organization() {}

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

And below is my Person entity:@Entity

```
@Table(name = "Person")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @Column(name="person_Id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column(name="Email",unique = true)
    private String email;
    @Column(name="FirstName")
    private String first_name;
    @Column(name="LastName")
    private String last_name;
    @Column(name="Description")
    private String description;

    //@Embedded
    private Address address;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Organization organization;

    public Organization getOrganization() {
      return organization;
    }

    public void setOrganization(Organization organization) {
        this.organization = organization;
    }

    public Person() {}


    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getFirst_name() {
        return first_name;
    }

    public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
    }

    public String getLast_name() {
        return last_name;
    }

    public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

when trying to create person. Below is my create method:

```
public Person createPerson(String f_name, String l_name, String email, String city, String state,
                               String zipCode, String street, String description, Long id) {

        Person person = null;
        //f_name, l_name, email are required parameters if empty return null and throws an exception..
        if(f_name.isEmpty() || l_name.isEmpty() || email.isEmpty()) {

            return person;
        }
        else {
            Session session = null;
            Transaction transaction = null;
            try {
                session = sessionFactory.openSession();
                transaction = session.beginTransaction();
                person = new Person();
                person.setFirst_name(f_name);
                person.setLast_name(l_name);
                person.setEmail(email);
                person.setDescription(description);
                Address address = new Address();
                address.setStreet(street);
                address.setZipCode(zipCode);
                address.setState(state);
                address.setCity(city);
                person.setAddress(address);
/* checks to see if id of organization exist if so add to list if not don't do anything.*/
                if(id!=null) {
                    Organization organization = session.get(Organization.class, id);
                    if (organization != null) {
     /* adds id of organization to person table and vice versa.*/
                        person.setOrganization(organization);
                        organization.getPersonCollection().add(person);
                    } else {
                        //do nothing
                    }
                }
                session.save(person);
                transaction.commit();
            } catch (HibernateException ex) {
                if (transaction != null)
                    transaction.rollback();
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (session != null)
                    session.close();
            }
            return person;
        }
    }
```

I am able to create both person and organization and persist to database. But when i try to add an organization to a person Row in database i cannot add the relationship(verified when i tried looking up database itself) and also no response as i get a lazy initialization collection error as well. Please has anyone encountered this problem

Comment: Are you sure the organization id you are sending isnt null ?

Comment: You can remove the JoinTable in Organization and do just this @JoinColumn(name="person_Id") and make fetch = FetchType.EAGER for the time-being so that Lazy loading erro goes away and check.

Answer (score 0):

I just executed the code snippet you gave in hibernate with the following simplified structure which works perfectly fine. You should start from here and modify as per your needs.

```
Entity
@Table(name="organization")
public class Organization {

    @Id
    @Column(name="org_Id")
    private long id;
    private String name, description;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<Person> personCollection = new ArrayList<Person>();

    public Collection<Person> getPersonCollection() {
        return personCollection;
    }

    public void setPersonCollection(Collection<Person> personCollection) {
        this.personCollection = personCollection;
    }


    public Organization() {}

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Person")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @Column(name="person_Id")
    private long id;
    @Column(name="Email",unique = true)
    private String email;
    @Column(name="FirstName")
    private String first_name;
    @Column(name="LastName")
    private String last_name;
    @Column(name="Description")
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne()
    private Organization organization;

    public Organization getOrganization() {
      return organization;
    }

    public void setOrganization(Organization organization) {
        this.organization = organization;
    }

    public Person() {}

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getFirst_name() {
        return first_name;
    }

    public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
    }

    public String getLast_name() {
        return last_name;
    }

    public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

EDIT : The CascadeType.ALL from Person side of the relationship has been moved to the Organization side of the relationship.Because you want when organization is deleted Person should also get deleted, but not the other way round.

Comment: when i tried your approach i noticed when i added a person to the collection instead of retaining the same id for organization it incremented when i made an update to personCollection

Comment: what annotation are you using for id generation ?

Comment: I think I know , why it is hapenning, remove the CascadeType.ALL from Person side of the relationship and put it in the Organization side of the relationship.Bcoz you want when organization is deleted  Person should also get deleted, but not the other way round.